# How do I retrieve anything from cloud datastore in node?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to access data that I have stored in datastore (in datastore mode). For some reason, I can't access any data it seems.

Things I've tried.

1. Access using a key

```
const datastore = new Datastore({projectId: '...'});

const key = datastore.key([<kind>, <id>]);
    return datastore.get(key, (err, entity, x) => {
        console.log("yolo", err, entity, x);
        return entity;
    });
```

2. Using a query

```
const query = 
        datastore.createQuery(<kind>);
return datastore.runQuery(query, (err, e, nq) => {
    console.log(err, e, nq);
    return e;
});
```

Both of the above yields no result. I am 100% sure I have typed the `kind` correctly.

Comment: Are you waiting on the return of runQuery?  It's unclear from your code if you expect your query function to return a promise or a query response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a stupid mistake on my end, but I keep the question in case someone else does the same mistake.

What I did when I created the entry in datastore was that I put it in a namespace, but then I didn't provide the namespace when I queried for it. Just providing the namespace and I was all good.